# Trying to append/prepend multiple paragraphs?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with appending or prepending text with automatically placed line returns in it between paragraphs. For example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#somelink').click(function () {
            $('#somediv').append("<p>Here's my first paragraph blah blah blah</p>
    <p>Here's my second paragraph blah blah blah blah</p>
    <p>Oh here's a third paragraph blah blah</p>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

doesn't seem to work because of the line return between paragraphs. I found if the `<p>` tags are right up next to one another it's fine, for example:

```
<p>first paragraph</p><p>second paragraph</p>
```

rather than:

```
<p>first paragraph</p>
<p>second paragraph</p>
```

Hopefully that makes sense. The issue is the text being placed by these appends is user generated. If I'm updating the text content it's fine, because I know to eliminate the line returns for the text I enter. However if my client ends up taking over updates and uses the CMS's built-in text editor to say add a new paragraph, it'll automatically create line returns and break the script. Basically the text editor automatically formats the text like the not working example above.

Is there any way I can have the function remove those line breaks and get the `<p>` tags to run right next to each other? Or is there a way to preserve the text coming in as is, with the tags, that doesn't break the script?

Comment: why not just build a string without the line breaks and then append it?

Comment: basic javascript syntax. breaking a line in a string declaration breaks javascript.

Comment: @Rusty

I would, but the text going into the script might eventually not be typed in by me, but generated from a text editor in the CMS, which automatically adds paragraph tags and line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't support multiline strings the way you are trying. You have to use the `+` opperator or put all the lines of text into an array, like so:

```
$('#somediv').append(
  [
    "<p>Here's my first paragraph blah blah blah</p>",
    "<p>Here's my second paragraph blah blah blah blah</p>",
    "<p>Oh here's a third paragraph blah blah</p>"
  ].join('')
);
```

Or with the `+` opperator:

```
$('#somediv').append(
    "<p>Here's my first paragraph blah blah blah</p>" +
    "<p>Here's my second paragraph blah blah blah blah</p>" +
    "<p>Oh here's a third paragraph blah blah</p>"
);
```

Comment: Hi luk3thomas 
Can I have the script add the "," if it's an array or add the + operator? If so, how?

Comment: No, you'll have to specify it like my example.

Comment: The only issue is the text would be generated by the built in text editor in the CMS I'm using. And it will just render paragraphs in `<p>` tags.  I'm thinking I have to approach this a different way to work with this specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

oke, sorry if i'm off mark with this answer.

But as you're saying content is inserted by a cms, i'm thinking of something like a textarea where the user puts in his text, clicks the link and the content entered should show somewhere else. This makes me believe that you want a dynamic script, and not a static one as you are writing with your sample code.

dynamic script will get the content from the textarea and work with that, instead of defining the content right in your script.

thus perhaps you are looking for something more like this. you can simple copy paste into a new document to try it out.

if you want to replace the content in the contentholder each time you click the update button.
you should use

```
$("#contentholder").html(inputData)
```

instead of

```
$("#contentholder").append(inputData)
```

heads up: if you use .html() function

```
&lt;p&gt;
```

will be replaced by text that looks like a `<p>`-tag, so you might need to sanitize input first, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#update").on('click', function(){
                //take content from textare
                var inputData = $("#input").val();
                $("#contentholder").append(inputData);
            });


        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- say this is the so called text editor -->
<textarea id='input' cols='50' rows='5'>
    &lt;p&gt;This is some sample text&lt;p&gt;

    &lt;p&gt;followed by some other text that was split by a linebreak and each text was wrapped in a p-element
</textarea>
<!-- submit the texteditor text -->
<button id='update'>click me to update</button>

<!-- put the text in a new something -->
<div id='contentholder'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this helps, have to go, no time to reread, so sorry for any mistakes but the actual script should help you along if i'm understanding what you're trying to do

Comment: That's really close! The only thing is where the text ends up and where it's typed in are two separate places in a sense. Like ok, I go in type in the text editor in the CMS's manager and create a new text resource, I can then call that resource different places were need be.

so if it could be where `var inputData = $("#input").val();` and that #input is instead the resource call code, that would be it.

Comment: Basically the text input and the text output aren't happening on the same page. The input is happening behind the scenes and then appears wherever I need it to. The problem is, is that it's being generated with the paragraph tags and breaks because that's just the way this CMS outputs text made with the built in text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#somelink').click(function () {
            $('#somediv').append("<p>Here's my first paragraph blah blah blah</p>\
                <p>Here's my second paragraph blah blah blah blah</p>\
                <p>Oh here's a third paragraph blah blah</p>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can continue a string on the next line by escaping the newline character with a \

Comment: Is there a way I can have the script add the "\" to every new paragraph? It's great solution if there's only one paragraph being placed like if I had:

`$('#somediv').append("<p>user entered paragraph here</p>\");`

but if there's two paragraphs entered for example, would it end up being:

`$('#somediv').append("<p>user entered paragraph here</p>\
<p>second paragraph entered by user</p>");`

Where the "\" was placed on the first one fine, but not the second. If that makes sense.

Comment: The \ is required *by* the script, so it can't be added by it.  It's a way of saying "this string value continues on the next line", without using "<p>paragragh1</p>" + "<p>paragragh2</p>" + "<p>paragragh3</p>" etc..