# How to generate same HTML inside head tags on a multiple page website without copying/pasting?

Tags: php, html

I've googled this question but have so far been unsuccessful at finding an answer, so I thought I'd ask here.  I was wondering if I have any options for recreating the meta data within the head tags in HTML for a multiple page website without just copying/pasting it for each new page.  I've seen on here examples using jQuery or PHP for loading pre-defined navigation and header menus that repeat across web pages, but what about the info in the head?  I was hoping to use something like nodejs to do this, but I have not seen an example on how it could be done.

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="_js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_js/includes.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="HMTL5Shiv\html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="topHeader">
        <!-- Header loaded from separate file -->
    </header>
    <div class="navigation">
        <!-- Navigation menu loaded from separate file-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, are you using PHP or nodejs? If you've seen this done with navigation, just do it the same way. You can put what ever you want in the file and include it where ever you want it. You can also look into using some template engine.

Comment: If you want to extract the code inside <head> tag take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471840/how-to-get-head-and-body-tags-as-a-string-from-html-string/13472335

Comment: I will use anything.  I'm making a website from scratch -- which I haven't done since high school, so I'm open to any solution.

Comment: Create a header.php file, and use `require_once 'path/to/header.php';`

Answer (score 3):

PHP can be used to do this even with the information in the head tags.
Just be sure to name your files .php
So for example
You would have an head.php file which will contain only the head tags and whatever is between them, and in the index.php file on the beginning of the file you would write `<?php include_once "head.php" ?>` just keep in mind that you need to provide the accurate path to the file that you are including( this example is for when the files are in the same folder), and than you can just paste this instead of whole chunks of code.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've found one way to do this, but not sure if it's the best way.  This uses jquery.

My html changes to the following:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head id="headTag">
    <script src="_js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_js/includes.js"></script> 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="HMTL5Shiv\html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="topHeader">
        <!-- Header loaded from separate file -->
    </header>
    <div class="navigation">
        <!-- Navigation menu loaded from separate file-->
    </div>
</body>
```

Then my includes.js file changes to the following.  The prepend function will write the redundant head data each time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#headTag').prepend(
    [
        '<meta charset="UTF-8">',
        '<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->',         
        '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">',
        '<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">',
        '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">'
    ].join('')
    );
$('.topHeader').load('Reusable/header.html');
$('.navigation').load('Reusable/nav.html');
});
```

I've shorted the amount of stuff in the head tags just to make this example easier to read, but this does get rid of a lot of copy paste.

This post was helpful as well for figuring this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14858617/8488401